# round function returns inconsistent results

Tags: r

Why `round(4.5)` is `4` and `round(3.5)` is also `4`?

Can anybody explain?

Comment: Probably http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/i_BankersRounding.htm

Comment: Use `?round`, which will show "... Note that for rounding off a 5, the IEC 60559 standard is expected to be used, ‘go to the even digit’. Therefore round(0.5) is 0 and round(-1.5) is -2. ...".

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/39892999/3871924

Comment: Thanks "67342343".. Got the answer

Comment: With `cbind((x <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19)/200000), round(x, 5))` I also get the effects of numerical imprecession